# Create a widget that acts as a terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, streamlit

I need to write a Streamlit app that acts as a Terminal, meaning that it behaves exactly like the terminal would, including by asking the user for input() when required by the script.

The script "danse_macabre.py" is a command line text RPG, so the user needs to give regular inputs and get responses from the system. It works well in the Terminal but I wanted to make a web version of it using Streamlit, hence my question.

Here what I got so far, but it doesn't work, it keeps loading forever.

Can you help ?

```
import streamlit as st
import subprocess

st.title("Command-line interface")

# Define the command to be executed
cmd = ["python", "danse_macabre.py"]

# Create a subprocess object
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

# Loop until the Python program exits
while process.poll() is None:
    # Check if the program has output
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output:
        st.text(output.strip())

    # Check if the program has an error
    error = process.stderr.readline()
    if error:
        st.error(error.strip())

    # Get user input using a Streamlit text_input component
    user_input = st.text_input("Input", "")

    # Pass user input to the Python program
    if user_input:
        process.stdin.write(user_input + "\n")
        process.stdin.flush()
```

Comment: Can you describe better the UI that you expect? For example I think that is not a good idea to create each while new text_input, maybe that should be ported on top with a button to send so you continuously put text, when the terminal stop the people can insert text in the box and press a button.

Answer (score 0):

It was much much more difficult than I though, Streamlit is not meant to be plugged to external data updated live and python handles very poorly the communication with an outside script that may block the thread.

But after all the pain, here is the gain :

```
import streamlit as st
import pexpect
import time

if 'child' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['child'] = pexpect.spawn("python danse_macabre.py", encoding='utf-8', timeout=None)

child = st.session_state['child']

if 'messages' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['messages'] = []

st.title("Danse Macabre AI Text RPG")

st.header("The first Text RPG powered by ChatGPT")

st.write("version : alpha 0.0.1")

# creating a single-element container
placeholder = st.empty()

user_input = st.text_input("What do you do or say ?")
if user_input :
    child.sendline(str(user_input))
    user_input=""

while True:
    with placeholder.container():
        #Let's see if there's a new message
        try :
            #If there's no exception it means yes
            line = child.read_nonblocking(size=1000, timeout=0)
            #Let's add it to the list of messages
            st.session_state['messages'].append(line)
        except:
            pass

        # Display the list of messages in the placeholder
        for msg in st.session_state['messages']:
            st.write(msg)
    #Try again in X sec
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

(you can see it live here : https://huggingface.co/spaces/Taiko3615/Danse_Macabre_AI_Text_RPG )

Comment: Seems to have a bug, cool idea though. 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "danse_macabre.py", line 511, in <module> main() File "danse_macabre.py", line 307, in main nextseq=sequence( File "danse_macabre.py", line 508, in sequence if secondaryControl is not None and "CLUE" in control.group(0): AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @DrSocket Try the latest version on the huggingface, it should work :-)